# Can I get the audioStream of other apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-audiomanager

I want to analyse the audio spectrum of my music player app for my bluetooth-Led project.

But as far as I understood this article:

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#REMOTE_SUBMIX
```

There is no way for third party apps to capture the audiostream of other apps.

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As of Android Q, this is possible (in apps that allow it) with the AudioPlaybackCapture API:

> This API gives apps the ability to copy the audio being played by other apps. This feature is the analog of screen capture, but for audio. The primary use case is for streaming apps that want to capture the audio being played by games.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/playback-capture)